# htaccess rewrite interfering with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Basics:

main site is at: www.example.com

wordpress install is at: www.example.com/blog

client wants some pages within wordpress accessible via: www.example.com/advice/some-page

rewriteengine is working in general but:

if i use htaccess in a directory /advice to redirect any requests for /advice/some-page to /blog/some-page, i see the correct content, but the url is /blog/some-page. i'd like google and users to see /advice/some-page.

my current htaccess in /advice dir:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [R]
```

I'm really bad at rewrites so any help gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the [R] flag :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1
```

Comment: excellent - almost. That gets me the correct obscured URL (/advice/some-page) but without the content - just the default wordpress page not found page. Maybe I should try it at the server root...?

Comment: That's weird since it was working with the R flag ... yes try it in the root :| (but you will need to change the last line to : 
`RewriteRule ^advice/(.*)$ blog/$1`)

Comment: thanks. that's what made me think wordpress rewrites might be interfering. tried at the root with those changes and same issue - URL is correct but wordpress doesn't display page. any thoughts on debugging exactly what wordpress is doing? thanks

Comment: You can activate rewriting logs and see what is realy happening

Comment: hmm - ok. bear with me whilst i look that up. i just tried turning off WP permalinks, so that it is displaying the ?page_id= in the URL. /advice/?page_id=1 seems to redirect to /blog/?page_id=1, even with the [R] turned off, which suggest WP is messing with it.

Comment: Yup - as I thought - server is remotely hosted and i can't enable rewritelog. i think wordpress is basically overriding the previous rewrite, so may not be possible